# Linking CSS in PHP

Tags: php, html

my CSS file "styles.css" isn't loading. I'm on a mac and my PHP server is set to be loading from my "PHP" folder on my desktop.

Here is the file path to the css folder: /Users/evanbutler/Desktop/PHP/css

Code from the PHP doc:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Users/evanbutler/Desktop/PHP/css/styles.css">
<title>Create a Business Card</title>
```

Answer (score 4):

Proper way is copy style.css from your desktop to project folder/css. then include css by href="css/styles.css"

They are four method to link css file into html:

1. Linking to a separate CSS file

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css" />
2. Embedding CSS into the HTML

   <style media="screen" type="text/css">
   Add style rules here
   </style>
3. Adding Inline CSS to HTML tags

   ```
   <h2 style="color:red;background:black;">This is a red heading with a black background</h2>
   ```
4. Importing a CSS file from within CSS

   @import "newstyles.css";

Answer (score 1):

You should use a relative path to your css file from your root folder of your working project. Are you using an environment like **XAMPP** to test your local project on? 
If so, your css relative url would be a `href="css/styles.css"`

Comment: Where is your index.php or index.html file located in your directory system?

Comment: You'll need some way to use your computer as a server in order to view anything you're doing with PHP. That means you'll have to install Apache and Mysql at least (or some other database engine). An easy way to do this is to download a packaged deal, which includes Apache, PHP, and Mysql.

You can get these for Windows (check out WAMP or XAMPP), Mac (MAMP), or Linux (LAMP). It makes things a lot easier.

Comment: The PHP and html files are located at /Users/evanbutler/Desktop/PHP

Comment: Started using MAMP and figured everything out, just had to change the Apache Port to 8000 and linked the bootstrap file from the document root instead of a website. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You're welcome. It's pretty standard to use a development environment to test out your project along the way before you deploy it live. You should turn on error reporting as well so you can debug the stuff as you go.